# Conditional labeling in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, conditional

I'd like to create a rule-based label in QGIS and wrote the following expression, but somehow it doesn't work - could someone tell me what's wrong?

```
 if( "FLN" > 0,
"FLN" || '\n' || "FSN__ZAE" || '\n'  || "FSN_NEN",
"FLN_2" || '\n' || "FSN__ZAE_2" || '\n'  || "FSN_NEN_2")
```

So the column "FLN" has some empty fields, in case it is empty, I want the label to display "FLN_2" etc. instead.

Comment: Do you have more than this rule?

Comment: If you have a null value in any of the field the || operator will return null, it's safer to use the CONCAT fonction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `coalesce` function. It returns the first non NULL value.

```
coalesce("FLN","FLN_2") || '\n' || coalesce("FSN__ZAE","FSN__ZAE_2“) || '\n'  || coalesce("FSN_NEN","FSN_NEN_2")
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Rule-based labeling, the rule must evaluate to either `True` or `False`.

Your if condition is returning the label you want to display. You should set the label text under the Text section. Example:

[image]

But if you only have that one condition and you dont need to set different fonts, etc. you can use Single labels with a case when:

```
CASE
    WHEN "field1" IS NULL THEN 'Field2 value is: ' || "field2"
    ELSE 'Field1 value is: ' || "field1"
END
```

[image]